# CloudKit hierarchy is not considered on fetch

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, realm, cloudkit

I'm using [IceCream](https://github.com/caiyue1993/IceCream) framework to handle synchronization between CloudKit and local Realm database, everything works great but on relations and child objects it sucks. please read my full explanation:

**Models:**

```
@objcMembers
class Task: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var title: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var project: Project?
    dynamic var isDeleted = false
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
@objcMembers
class Project: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var startDate: Date = Date()
    dynamic var isDeleted = false

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

**Expected behavior:**

Look for `CKReference` in model properties and fetch that object earlier than the model object itself.
If task's project is not nil:

search for that object in local database and set project property.
if not exists in local,first fetch project and then create task and set project property.

so the main questions is:

***Is it possible to add hierarchy on fetching objects?***

***Is fetching based on last modified date?***

**Actual behavior:**

I have 2 tasks saved in cloud both connected to ProjectA, project field in CloudKit Dashboard referenced as well and it's confirmed.
I have tested more than 10 times, randomly task1 get project right and task2 project is nil and vice versa. there's no custom implementation and I'm sure it happens because sometimes Project objects fetched earlier than Task objects and sometimes not.

better example:
`SyncEngine` starts fetching objects without considering hierarchy:

1. task2 fetched & there is no projects in local database, so `task2.project = nil`
2. projectA fetched.
3. task1 fetched & there is the project needed, so `task1.project = projectA`

further thanks to all contributors.

[link to this issue on Github](https://github.com/caiyue1993/IceCream/issues/200)